# Jquery make context menu with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my code, it works perfect without using array, and creates context menu on div, but now i want to create some context menu items from array. when i apply array it is showing all items of array in one line and separates by Comma (,) . but i need all items in different rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/danial786zz/sobnwgeb/   this fiddle is working perfect but i need to make items from array.

```
$('#div_id").chromeContext({
items: [

      { title: array,         onclick: function () { RToTb(array_name) } },
      { title: 'properties'   onclick: function () { abc();            } },
      { title: 'view'         onclick: function () { def();            } }

    ]
```

});

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Derek check my FIDDLE , right click on a div it will open small menu... i want to make that menu through array.. ( but in a fiddle you can see it is hardcoded )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you :

I have created an array out of another array and used that in the context menu.

```
 $(function(){
    var arr = ['1st Row', '2nd Row', '3rd Row'];
    var menuitems = [];
    $.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
       menuitems[index] =  { title: value, onclick: function () { RToTb(array_name) }};
    });

    $('#div_id').chromeContext({
       items : menuitems
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yunus_Aslam/fzth3ec2/)

Comment: Yes that is possible. In that case you have to make array of function names and use the array inside each in somewhat like
`onclick: function { functionname[i] }` where functionname is an array containing names of functions. Haven't tried this. You can give it a try. Ask help if needed but before that please try by yourself first.

Comment: hi Yunus i am stuck in this little problem  check this http://jsfiddle.net/danial786zz/ykL17tce/
it gives only last number when alert onclick

Comment: Hello.. This is another fiddle.. Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/Yunus_Aslam/jg5ksyyv/

Comment: you are really great..gud experiance you answer within minutes thanks, i am new going ahead if i got stuck i will message here thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It is about your array definition. There should be objects inside each array element.

```
$(function(){
   var arr=[];
   arr[0]= { 'title': '1st row', 'onclick:': function () { RToTb(array_name); } };
   arr[1]={ 'title': '2st row', 'onclick:': function () { RToTb(array_name); }};
   arr[2]={ 'title': '3st row', 'onclick:': function () { RToTb(array_name); }};


   $('#div_id').chromeContext({
      items: arr
   });
});
```

Check the link below for working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/v7v8f386/1/